# Java Multithread Priorities

Tags: java

If you are running multiple threads all with the same priority, why do you not need to call the yield or sleep method in any of the threads? I must have misunderstood how threading works. I was under the assumption that if two threads are of the same priority, one will finish before the other is started on a single core system. That is, unless you call one of the control functions ie.) yield() sleep() join() ... ect

Anyone with the knowledge of this subject I would appreciate any clarifications you may have for me.

StackOverFlow would not let me add a comment to your answer:

Also according to my book: "The JVM always picks the currently runnable thread with the highest priority. A lower priority thread can run only when no higher-priority threads are running."

Comment: Even if you have one core, this core might be able to process multiple threads at the same time.

Comment: the functions you mentioned are used to avoid deadlock. Threads are independent of working otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> why do you not need to call the yield or sleep method in any of the threads?

Scheduling is done pre-emptively.  You don't need to call yield or sleep or wait or call a blocking operation for the OS to suspend you thread.

> I was under the assumption that if two threads are of the same priority, one will finish before the other is started on a single core system.

Even if one thread is maximum priority and one is the lowest priority, it doesn't mean one will finish before the other.

> unless you call one of the control functions ie.) yield() sleep() join()

Calling these methods can give up the CPU but this doesn't mean the OS won't suspect a thread because these were not called., note: they don't have to.

Comment: Hey I was unable to comment earlier so I added it to my question: "Also according to my book: "The JVM always picks the currently runnable thread with the highest priority. A lower priority thread can run only when no higher-priority threads are running." "Is this simply incorrect information?

Comment: @DCS_Kurtis_IT_Manager The JVM has no say in when threads are run.  The OS does this. It could have been talking about green threads which was only used on Solaris up to 1998.

Comment: Peter, the book I am reading seems to make no reference to Solaris. The book is titled "Java Programing" I am going to make a test program with max priority vs. lowest priority. I will let it run for a while and post the results. Thank you for your assistance